# increasing the line thickness of geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this ggplot:

```
ggplot(dt.m, aes(x=pct.on.OAC.cont,y=Number.of.Practices, fill=Age.Group)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position=position_dodge()) +   
    geom_smooth(aes(x=pct.on.OAC.cont,y=Number.of.Practices, colour=Age.Group), se=F)
```

How can I increase the thickness of the lines drawn by geom_smooth ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Do the `size` argument do what you want:

```
+ geom_smooth(aes(x=pct.on.OAC.cont, y=Number.of.Practices, colour=Age.Group), 
               se=F, size=10)
```

alternatively, you could change `size` to `lwd`, but it is standard to use `size`.

Comment: Just an update. Since ggplot2 3.4.0, `size` is deprecated. Now use `linewidth`, instead.